# Does anyone know any people-based source code audit website/forum/comunity for JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Hello I'm writing a jQuery code for my application and got some issues (like function called once, running three times).
I must know if exist any site that people audit source code and comment my mistakes..

most of my code is like this i/e:

```
$('a.openBox').click(function(){
  //do something
  $('.box').show();
  $('a.openModal','.box').click(function(){
     $.openModal(some, parameters)
  });
});

$.openModal = function(foo,bar){
    //do something
    $('a.close').click(function(){
        $('#modal').hide();
     });
    $('input.text').click(function(){
        $.anotherFunction();
     });
});
```

does am I doing something obviously wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any source code audit like that -- certainly not for free!  This website is pretty good for specific problems though...

In this case, the problem is that you are continually binding more and more events.  For instance, with the following code:

```
$('a.openBox').click(function(){
  //do something
  $('.box').show();
  $('a.openModal','.box').click(function(){
     $.openModal(some, parameters)
  });
});
```

This code says "whenever the user clicks on an `a.openbox` element, show all `.box` elements and **bind a new click handler to all `.box a.openModal` elements**".  This means that you will add another handler to `.box a.openModal` every time you click on `a.openbox`.  I can't believe this is what you want to do!

It is difficult to work out what the correct code should be without knowing the context and exactly what you want to happen.  My advice for you in the first instance would be to do some reading up on Javascript events and event handlers, particularly as they are implemented in jQuery.

Comment: yes, is that what i want, but when i click on a.openModal it runs the $.openModal() content three or more times...